# Save data in ArrayList in activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, oncreate

I am a new android programmer.
I have 4 activities: A B C D.
The order is A -> B -> C -> D -> A and A -> D using buttons.
I want to save data in ArrayList that is in activity D.
The problem is that when I move from D to A and come back to D, the data in the ArrayList didn't save.
Code for D activity here:

```
public class SchedulerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public String name = "";
    public String number = "";
    public String date = "";
    public String hour = "";
    public ArrayList<EventClass> scheduler = new ArrayList<>();

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scheduler);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SchedulerActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
        if (extras != null) {
            String sender = extras.getString("sender");
            if(sender.compareTo("Hours") == 0) {
                name = extras.getString("name");
                number = extras.getString("number");
                date = extras.getString("date");
                hour = extras.getString("hour");
                Date real_date = new Date();
                SimpleDateFormat formatter1=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                try {
                    real_date = formatter1.parse(date);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                scheduler.add(new EventClass(real_date, name, number, "", hour));
                for (EventClass event : scheduler){
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    final TextView t = new TextView(this);
                    t.setText(event.toString());
                    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
                    linearLayout.addView(t, params);
                }

            }
            else{
                for (EventClass event : scheduler){
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    final Button btn = new Button(this);
                    final TextView t = new TextView(this);
                    t.setText(event.toString());
                    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
                    linearLayout.addView(btn, params);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to change my ArrayList when C->D occurs and print it and when D->A occurs I just want to print it. I know that I can with SharedPreferences but for the first step, I want to do this with ArrayList.
What's the best way to do this?

Comment: have you tried using intents?

Comment: yes, sure.
like this:
Intent intent = new Intent(SchedulerActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
that's the way that I move btw activities.

Answer (score 1):

Creating static objects is not a good approach. So you can use android activity stack in-place of using static **Arraylist**.  Android activities are stored in the activity stack. Going back to a previous activity could mean two things.

You opened the new activity from another activity with startActivityForResult. In that case you can just call the finishActivity() function from your code and it'll take you back to the previous activity.
Keep track of the activity stack. Whenever you start a new activity with an intent you can specify an intent flag like FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT or FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP. You can use this to shuffle between the activities in your application.

Comment: I am not sure I understood. If my top is A and I need to move in this way: A -> B -> C -> D ->A, I can use FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP in B and C and when D will finish, it's automatically moving to A?

Answer (score 0):

The scheduler is a non-static field in the SchedulerActivity which means that its existance is tied to the instance of the activity. When the activity instance is destroyed, and that might happen for example when the screen orientation is destroyed or you move to another activity, so are all its non-static fields. You can change that by adding a static keyword before your field:

```
public static ArrayList<EventClass> scheduler = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now, your field is tied to the class itself, not the instance, whitch means it wont be destroyed along with the instance. But it also means that it is shared between all instances and must be referenced with the class name outside of the class body:

```
EventClass event = SchedulerActivity.scheduler.get(0)
```

Comment: Glad i could help

Answer (score 0):

A good approach is saving your data in a local database, like [Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room). You need to save before go to new activity, and get it back on **OnResume()**.